# Preferred way to make a mutable copy of a non-mutable object?

Tags: ios, foundation

There are 2 choices (possibly more). Using NSSet as an example:

```
NSMutableSet * mutableSet = [ NSMutableSet setWithSet:nonMutableSet ] ;
```

or

```
NSMutableSet * mutableSet = [ [ nonMutableSet mutableCopy ] autorelease ] ;
```

Is there any difference between these two implementations? Is one "more efficient" at all? (Other examples would be NSArray/NSMutableArray and NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Good question, and I suspect there could potentially be a lot of debate on this.

Comment: If you would like to do everybody a favor, benchmark it and answer the question yourself :) I suspect there shouldn't be much of a difference, though.

Comment: @fzwo I guess I could do that.. Although it's partly a programming philosophy question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Benchmark fun! :)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{ @autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableSet *masterSet = [NSMutableSet set];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        [masterSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }

    clock_t start = clock();

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            [NSMutableSet setWithSet:masterSet];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"a: --- %lu", clock() - start);

    sleep(1);

    start = clock();

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            [[masterSet mutableCopy] autorelease]; 
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"b: --- %lu", clock() - start);

    return 0;
} }
```

On my machine (10.7), setWithSet: is ~3x slower than -mutableCopy (Does somebody want to try on iOS 5? :) )

Now, the question is: why?

-mutableCopy is spending most of its time in CFBasicHashCreateCopy() (see [CFBasicHash.m](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.15/CFBasicHash.m)).  This appears to be copying the hash buckets directly, with no rehashing.

```
Running  Time   Self  Symbol Name
256.0ms  61.5%  0.0   -[NSObject mutableCopy]
256.0ms  61.5%  0.0     -[__NSCFSet mutableCopyWithZone:]
256.0ms  61.5%  0.0       CFSetCreateMutableCopy
255.0ms  61.2%  156.0       CFBasicHashCreateCopy
97.0ms   23.3%  44.0          __CFSetStandardRetainValue
```

-setWithSet is enumerating through each value of the set, and then adding it to the new set.  From the implementation of CFBasicHashAddValue (again in [CFBasicHash.m](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.15/CFBasicHash.m)), it looks like it is rehashing each value in the set.

```
Running    Time Self    Symbol Name
1605.0ms   86.0%    0.0     +[NSSet setWithSet:]
1605.0ms   86.0%    2.0       -[NSSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
1232.0ms   66.0%    68.0        -[__NSPlaceholderSet initWithObjects:count:]
1080.0ms   57.8%    299.0         CFBasicHashAddValue
324.0ms    17.3%    28.0        -[NSSet getObjects:count:]
272.0ms    14.5%    75.0          __CFBasicHashFastEnumeration
```

This rehash makes sense at the CFSet level.  CFSets take a CFSetHashCallBack in the callBacks parameter; thus, two CFSets of CFNumbers could have a different hashing routine specified.  Foundation's NSSet uses CFSet under-the-hood, and has a CFSetHashCallBack function which invokes `-[NSObject hash]`.  (Although I guess that Apple could optimize this case and avoid the rehash when two sets have the same hash callback).

Note that this benchmark is for NSSet (of NSNumbers) only, other collection classes may have different performance characteristics.

Comment: I believe Arrays can have different backing implementations (in private subclasses of the NSArray class cluster) depending on circumstances such as number of items, which further complicates benchmarking (but generally improves performance).

Comment: Yep!  Also, the number of objects in the collection can make a difference as well.  Just as a note, for arrays using the above benchmark, it looks like -mutableCopy/-autorelease is slightly *slower*  These things are frequently tuned - it's a good idea to redo the benchmarks ever so often than make assumptions about performance characteristics of Foundation classes :)